# What does wxPuts do?

Tags: c++, function, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm trying to learn wxWidgets using [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/wxwidgetstutorial/helperclasses/). It directs me to use a function called wxPuts() to put text in the console. My program compiles fine, but nothing shows up. I've searched for documentation to see exactly what wxPuts() is supposed to do so that I can get the settings right, but I'm having no luck.
Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <wx\string.h>

int main()
{
    wxPuts(wxT("A wxWidgets console application."));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is wxPuts() supposed to do? I'm using Code::Blocks, but I also have Eclipse CDT and Microsoft Visual C++. How do I set up my IDE, so that wxPuts() gives the correct output?

Comment: Are you sure your application is console and not windows type ?

Comment: What would a windows type application do?

Comment: A windows type application typically puts up a windows which is not console

Comment: I don't see a window either. How do I get the window up?

Comment: Without any code or more detailed information.. You will not get any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel kinda dumb. It turns out I wasn't waiting long enough for the text to pop up. For some reason it takes a very long time. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

I had to `# include <wx/crt.h>`

to get `wxPuts` to work using Code Blocks 17.12, wxWidgets 3.1.2 on Windows 7 Pro.

I received the advice to include crt.h from:

[Why doesn't Clion recognise WxPuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018383/why-doesnt-clion-recognise-wxputs)

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This function of `wx/string.h` library. It's show message in console. In order to work correctly. This should include some additional information in project properties. 
Right Click to Project Properties

> 1. Built -> C++ Compiler -> in Additional Options add "`wx-config --cxxflags`" without quotes
>
>    2. Built -> Linker -> in Additional Options add "`wx-config --libs`" without quotes

Then it should works fine.