# Why doesn't Clion recognise WxPuts?

Tags: wxwidgets

The wxPuts method used in this tutorial (http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/helperclasses/) doesn't work. Was it changed and the class is no longer available?

I tried searching online for some documentation about wxPuts and wxPrintf, but can't find anything relevant in the helper files in the wxWidg site.

```cpp
#include <wx/textfile.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    wxTextFile file(wxT("test.c"));

    file.Open();

    wxPrintf(wxT("Number of lines: %d\n"), file.GetLineCount());
    wxPrintf(wxT("First line: %s\n"), file.GetFirstLine().c_str());
    wxPrintf(wxT("Last line: %s\n"), file.GetLastLine().c_str());

    wxPuts(wxT("-------------------------------------"));

    wxString s;

    for ( s = file.GetFirstLine(); !file.Eof();
          s = file.GetNextLine() )
    {
        wxPuts(s);
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `int main(...)`. Look at the `/samples/minimal` for a good start with wxWidgets. There are just a bunch of cases where `main` can be used without initializing the wx libraries. Also, post the errors you get and where.

Answer (score 3):

wxWidgets provides wrappers for all standard CRT functions working with strings in order to allow calling them with `wxString` or `wchar_t` (wide) strings. These wrappers are not documented because it doesn't make much sense to re-document the standard functions, but basically for any `foo(const char* s)` in the standard library, you have `wxFoo(const wxString& s)` declared in `wx/crt.h` header. You have to include this header to get these declarations, however.

Also note that most of wxWidgets functionality can't be used before the [library is initialized](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.2/classwx_initializer.html).

TL;DR: you're missing `#include <wx/crt.h>`.